# C++ use of undeclared identifier IOKit Functions

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, iokit

I am getting an error building my c++ program on xcode. For each of the various fuctions of the IOKit I am getting "use of undeclared identifier". I really don't know why I am getting this error.  Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <xlnt/xlnt.hpp>
#include <xlnt/xlnt_config.hpp>
#include <IOKitLib.h>
#include <IOTypes.h>
#include <IOReturn.h>
#include <IOKitKeys.h>
#include <iokitmig.h>
#include <OSMessageNotification.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <paths.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>
#include <IOKit/serial/IOSerialKeys.h>
#include <IOKit/IOBSD.h>

#define LOCAL_ECHO
#ifdef LOCAL_ECHO
#define kOKResponseString “AT\r\r\nOK\r\n”
#else
#define kOKResponseString “\r\nOK\r\n”
#endif


#define kATCommandString        "AT\r"
#define kMyErrReturn            -1
enum {
kNumRetries = 3
};

static struct termios gOriginalTTYAttrs;



int main()
{
char path;
char text;

int fileDescriptor;
kern_return_t kernResult;
io_iterator_t serialPortIterator;
char deviceFilePath[MAXPATHLEN];
kernResult = MyFindModems(&serialPortIterator);
kernResult = MyGetModemPath(serialPortIterator, deviceFilePath,
                            sizeof(deviceFilePath));
```

Here is the image with all the errors shown: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1UZS.jpg
Any advice would be more than appreciated. Is it because I haven't declared the functions? 
Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: You certainly need to declare functions before you use them. For more specific help, please quote the **exact** error message.

Comment: please show the exact error message you are getting

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have just edited the thread by adding an image with all the errors that I am getting

Comment: Are you including the code that implements `MyFindModems` etc? according to your screenshot of errors (text, next time...) this has nothing to do with IOKit.

Comment: if I declare the function like this: kern_return_t MyFindModems(&serialPortIterator);      i get the following error("Cannot initialize a variable of type 'kern_return_t' (aka 'int') with an rvalue of type 'io_iterator_t *' (aka 'unsigned int *')"

Comment: @MosheGottlieb I believe I did it. I am following the following documentation:http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/WorkingWSerial/WorkingWithSerial.pdf

Comment: If you give it a look at page 7/8/9 you'll see that I have done everything that there's written. However, if you suggest me to use another library feel free to tell me

Comment: @aleeeee `MyXXX` functions are not APIs, these are samples from the document you sent, they show you how to use IOKit.

Comment: At the very least, copy their implementation (you can find it in the PDF) to your code, but that wasn't really the intention - you were supposed to look at it, see how they use the API and devise your own method.

Comment: @MosheGottlieb this is what I was thinking. Thanks for having confirmed my initial hypothesis. May I ask you what you mean with "copy their implementation"?

Comment: I am sorry for these questions but I am new to iokit and the last few days it has driven me crazy ahah